# Does Google's gsutil command line app work on 64 bit windows?

Tags: google-bigquery

is it possible to run Google's Big Query command line tool: gsutil on Windows 7 64 bit?

I could not get this to work because of a dependent Python module called: pyOpenSSL-0.13, which I could not install w/o building it using Microsoft Express 2008.  Just wondered if this was a known issue.

Thanks.

Comment: just confirming: are you talking about "bq" (the actual BigQuery command line tool) or gsutil (the tool for using Google Cloud Storage)?

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to answer. No, this is for utility gsutil.   To recap, the basic problem is install gsutils dependent python module for opensll (pyOpenSSL-0.13). It seemed that easy_install or pip would try to build the module when installing on a 64 bit Windows 7 box. Itried setting up a gcc/mingw and Microsoft Visual Studio Express environment but could not get this to work. Finally gave up and used 64 bit Centos OS virtual machine. Which for me isn't ideal since I need to move > 1TB of data into Big Query. I would rather go bare metal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK. I finally came up with a solution for those with a similar problem:

1. Install cygwin w/ dev tools (i.e. gcc compiler, make, automake, etc)
2. Install openssl-dev for cygwin.
3. Download pyOpenSSL-0.13 gzip file and decompress it into home folder. (Google for this)
4. run "python setup.py install" from inside a cygwin prompt.
5. Download gsutil source code from Google and decompress it into home folder.
6. run "python setup.py install" from inside a cygwin prompt.
7. cd to the gsutil directory
8. run ./gsutil

This solution worked for me on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine. It could be that I broke my installation and that others may not run into this problem. However, it does seem that OpenSSL support for gsutil on a Windows 64 bit machine running 64 bit python is non-existent.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the cygwin environment was 32-bit. But the end justified the means for me since I am now able to run gsutil on a 64 bit windows machine...